# AbstractMethodError ...RealmProxyMediator.getModelClasses()

Tags: android, realm

Iam using(trying to) Realm and the RealmSearchView (thorbenprimke).

Because of dublicate errors when making the apk file iam using the excludePackagingOptions, keepFirst for all the .so files.

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst("lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so")
        pickFirst("lib/x86/librealm-jni.so")`enter code here`
        pickFirst("lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so")
        pickFirst("lib/armeabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so")
        pickFirst("lib/mips/librealm-jni.so")
..
}
```

The projects build fine, but when iam calling Realm.getDefault(), i get the 
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.List io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.getModelClasses()"

My Realm config looks like this.

config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .name("myrealm.realm")
                .build();

Any suggestions would be appreciated? :)

Comment: It probably has to do with `excludePackagingOptions pickFirst()`, although knowing what the "duplicate errors" are would be helpful :P

Comment: Without pickFirst i cant create the apk file :)

Here are the log:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so
 File1: C:\Users\madsh\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.realm\realm-android\0.82.2\c6325383149a08e5cb668bdc4d3c790708636e47\realm-android-0.82.2.jar
 File2: ....\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\io.realm\realm-android-library\1.2.0\jni

Comment: That's because you are including both Realm 0.82.2 and Realm 1.2.0

Comment: You should remove `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2' ` from your build.gradle

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Iam using andori dstudio. The only realm import  i have is the   classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
and the   compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.1'

Comment: I have solved it my self. I changed the Realm plugin to 1.1 similar to the realm version in 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.1.
And still keeping the excludePackagingOptions

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it my self. I changed the Realm plugin to 1.1 similar to the realm version in 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.1. And still keeping the excludePackagingOptions –